# Combining data from two dataframe columns into one column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have time series data in two separate `DataFrame` columns which refer to the same parameter but are of differing lengths.

On dates where data only exist in one column, I'd like this value to be placed in my new column. On dates where there are entries for both columns, I'd like to have the mean value. (I'd like to join using the index, which is a datetime value)

Could somebody suggest a way that I could combine my two columns? Thanks.

Edit2: I written some code which should merge the data from both of my column, but I get a `KeyError` when I try to set the new values using my index generated from rows where my first df has values but my second df doesn't. Here's the code:

```
def merge_func(df):
    null_index = df[(df['DOC_mg/L'].isnull() == False) & (df['TOC_mg/L'].isnull() == True)].index
    df['TOC_mg/L'][null_index] = df[null_index]['DOC_mg/L']
    notnull_index = df[(df['DOC_mg/L'].isnull() == True) & (df['TOC_mg/L'].isnull() == False)].index
    df['DOC_mg/L'][notnull_index] = df[notnull_index]['TOC_mg/L']

    df.insert(len(df.columns), 'Mean_mg/L', 0.0)
    df['Mean_mg/L'] = (df['DOC_mg/L'] + df['TOC_mg/L']) / 2
    return df

merge_func(sve)
```

And here's the error:

```
KeyError: "['2004-01-14T01:00:00.000000000+0100' '2004-03-04T01:00:00.000000000+0100'\n '2004-03-30T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2004-04-12T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2004-04-15T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2004-04-17T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2004-04-19T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2004-04-20T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2004-04-22T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2004-04-26T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2004-04-28T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2004-04-30T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2004-05-05T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2004-05-07T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2004-05-10T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2004-05-13T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2004-05-17T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2004-05-20T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2004-05-24T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2004-05-28T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2004-06-04T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2004-06-10T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2004-08-27T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2004-10-06T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2004-11-02T01:00:00.000000000+0100' '2004-12-08T01:00:00.000000000+0100'\n '2011-02-21T01:00:00.000000000+0100' '2011-03-21T01:00:00.000000000+0100'\n '2011-04-04T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2011-04-11T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2011-04-14T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2011-04-18T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2011-04-21T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2011-04-25T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2011-05-02T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2011-05-09T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2011-05-23T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2011-06-07T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2011-06-21T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2011-07-04T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2011-07-18T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2011-08-31T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2011-09-13T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2011-09-28T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2011-10-10T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2011-10-25T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2011-11-08T01:00:00.000000000+0100' '2011-11-28T01:00:00.000000000+0100'\n '2011-12-20T01:00:00.000000000+0100' '2012-01-19T01:00:00.000000000+0100'\n '2012-02-14T01:00:00.000000000+0100' '2012-03-13T01:00:00.000000000+0100'\n '2012-03-27T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2012-04-02T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2012-04-10T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2012-04-17T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2012-04-26T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2012-04-30T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2012-05-03T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2012-05-07T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2012-05-10T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2012-05-14T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2012-05-22T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2012-06-05T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2012-06-19T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2012-07-03T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2012-07-17T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2012-07-31T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2012-08-14T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2012-08-28T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2012-09-11T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2012-09-25T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2012-10-10T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2012-10-24T02:00:00.000000000+0200'\n '2012-11-21T01:00:00.000000000+0100' '2012-12-18T01:00:00.000000000+0100'] not in index"
```

Comment: Look at this answer to merge [in case you need to add suffixes in cases of similarly named columns]: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906835/pandas-merging-join-dataframes/23921662#23921662" , Now read up on here: "http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?highlight=loc#indexing-and-selecting-data" To figure out how to select certain indexes. What you will want to do after the merge, find rows where a value is missing using variations of df[(df['colA'].isnull() == True) & (df['colB'].isnull() == False)], and set the value if missing. Then take the mean across colA and colB

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RyanG. My columns were already in the same `DataFrame` and share an index (which are date times). I wrote a function to find empty rows/take averages if both rows contain values however, I get a syntax error when I try to assign new values. I've added the new code to my original question.

Comment: I would return the dataframe after the loop is completed. Your close in your implementation, but here is another way to tackle this problem in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but you actually don't need to iterate over the rows when using the isnull() functions. by default

```
df[(df['DOC_mg/L'].isnull() == False) & (df['TOC_mg/L'].isnull() == True)].index
```

Will return just the index of the rows where `DOC_mg/L` is not null and `TOC_mg/L` is null.

Now you can do something like this to set the values for TOC_mg/L:

```
null_index = df[(df['DOC_mg/L'].isnull() == False) & \
                (df['TOC_mg/L'].isnull() == True)].index
df['TOC_mg/L'][null_index] = df['DOC_mg/L'][null_index] # EDIT To switch the index position.
```

This will use the index of the rows where TOC_mg/L is null and DOC_mg/L is not null, and set the values for TOC_mg/L to the those found in DOC_mg/L in the same rows.

***Note:*** This is not the accepted way for setting values using an index, but it is how I've been doing it for some time. Just make sure that when setting values, the left side of the equation is `df['col_name'][index]`. If `col_name` and `index` are switched you will set the values to a copy which is never set back to the original.

Now to set the mean, you can create a new column, we'll call this `Mean_mg/L` and set the value = 0.0. Then set this new column to the mean of both columns:

```
# Insert a new col at the end of the dataframe columns name 'Mean_mg/L' 
#     with default value 0.0
df.insert(len(df.columns), 'Mean_mg/L', 0.0)
# Set this columns value to the average of DOC_mg/L and TOC_mg/L
df['Mean_mg/L'] = (df['DOC_mg/L'] + df['TOC_mg/L']) / 2
```

In the columns where we filled null values with the corresponding column value, the average will be the same as the values.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I added an extra line to copy values from the 2nd `df` back to the 1st (I wasn't sure whether `Pandas` would skip `NaNs` when calculating the mean), ahead of calculating the mean. I get a `KeyError` saying that the `null_index` `not in index`. I don't understand why I get this error as the `df` used to generate the index is the same as the one I'm applying it to. Have I misunderstood the error?

Comment: Mhmm. It seems that depending on how the index is setup, you can't use the `df[null_index]['DOC_mg/L']` but instead use `df['DOC_mg/L'][null_index]`. This is interesting because I've never had this happen before, but it must have been just luck. I've updated the post to include the fix.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I also found an alternative solution using `.loc` ie `df.loc[null_index, 'TOC_mg/L'] = df['DOC_mg/L']`

Comment: I'm glad you found that. Using .loc[] is the accepted way of doing these types of operations. However, since I've been doing it the old way for so long, I've never fully adopted .loc[], but it's now apparent that key errors can exist, so I need to learn to use this way as well :D . Thanks for that.